# need some explanation about foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, symfony

I'm using symfony 4 and when I do links between tables there are indexes created. I do not understand how they work.

[image]

What is their purpose and why is it impossible to import data file into those files.
Is it possible to 'bypass' this mysql restriction and import data-files into mysql even if there is a constraint (without breaking the indexes)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL is a relational database system. If there is a relationship between 2 tables, it is there for a reason. Think of your entities in Symfony. If one entity (a primary entity) has several related entities and those related entities can only exist if there is a primary entity, then the constraint must exist to prevent orphaned records.

**For example:**
Consider the relationship between companies and divisions. A company can have 0 or more divisions, but a division can only exist as a part of a company. In this case, a record in the division table would have a reference to a record in the company table. However, a record in a company table would have no direct reference in MySQL to any records in the division table.

To prevent a division from being created without a company, you cannot insert a row into the division table that does not reference a record in the company table.

**To finally answer the question directly**, you can only import data that does not reference the primary table by removing the foreign key constraint (this will not destroy the index). Keep in mind that this will likely result in records that are "orphaned" and do not fit the business model you are trying to create.

Rather than removing the foreign key constraint, you should first import the data to the referenced table (scoring?) and then update the data being imported to contain the correct ids to reference the primary table.

Based on the information in the image provided, each record in the file being imported should have a value for scoring_id that is equal to (presumably) the id field in the scoring table. If there is some other piece of data that can be used to link the 2 tables, use that and configure your entities appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql FOREIGN KEY is used for data integrity. So what happens is you have a Foreign key which refers to column in another table .It's a way to link data relationships between tables

When Using Import if that key does not exist in the other table the mysql import will throw errors .

If you remove the FOREIGN KEY flag you would be able to import that table

refer to [MYSQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

on Foreign Keys

Answer (score 1):

Foreign keys will check if the other table has already that element that you try to enter.

What you can do for the import temporarily

> use FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS

Before the import  run

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

and When it is finished

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Or

> use DISABLE KEYS:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DISABLE KEYS;
```

and when the import is finished:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ENABLE KEYS;
```

Of course you have to change table_name